# regular expression to replace lastname, firstname middle initial to email format

Tags: regex

Need a little help creating a regular expression to take, for example :

```
Smith, John R
```

and turn it into

```
john.r.smith@gmail.com
```

Comment: regex is over kill when you can do something like split and join in your favorite language `echo "Smith, John R" | tr -d , | awk '{print tolower($0)}' | awk '{ print $2"."$3"."$1"@gmail.com" }'` gives:
`john.r.smith@gmail.com`

Comment: What about `Smith, John`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `regex` in `C++11`:

```
string s = "Smith, John R"; // to john.r.smith@gmail.com

const regex r("(.*), (.*) (.*)");  
const string fmt("$2.$3.$1@gmail.com");  

cout << regex_replace(s, r, fmt) << endl;
```

**Note:** this will give you `John.R.Smith@gmail.com`, you may further need to change it to lowercase if you need `john.r.smith@gmail.com`, which is quite a easy task.

Answer (score 2):

Since the language is not specified , i tried this in VIM and it works perfectly.

```
%s/\v(\w*),\s*(\w*)\s*(\w)/\L\2.\L\3.\1@gmail.com/
```

Attached is screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Same as previous answer, but in Shell:

```
echo "Smith, John R" | awk '{print tolower($0)}' | sed 's/\(.*\),\s\(.*\)\s\(.*\)/\2.\3.\1@gmail.com/g'
john.r.smith@gmail.com
```

Actually thanks to @KP6, I realized sed can lowercase too :)
So, much simpler version would be:

```
echo "Smith, John R" | sed 's/\(.*\),\s\(.*\)\s\(.*\)/\L\2.\L\3.\L\1@gmail.com/g'
john.r.smith@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Just capture the needed tokens:

```
(.+?),\s(.+?)\s(.+)
```

$1 is last name.

$2 is first name

$3 is middle name

Now build your email address.

As mention by other, regex seems like overkill